# How can i set a value to a property dynamically, by receiving the property to the function?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I have a function that loops on an array, gets the value of the field `Days` on all objects, and assigns them to the property `this.daysOptions`

this is the function:

```
getMultiPicklistValues() {
        var valuesArray = [];
        for(let i=0;i<this.assets.length;i++) {
            if(!valuesArray.includes(this.assets[i].Days)) {
                valuesArray.push(this.assets[i].Days);
            }
        }
        var newArray = [];
        for(var i=0;i<valuesArray.length;i++) {
            newArray.push({'key':i+1,'value':valuesArray[i]});
        }

        this.daysOptions = newArray;
    }
```

I want to make this function generic,
and assign `newArray` to some property, that will be changed dynamically, instead of assigning it to `this.daysOptions`

I changed the function to receive the field name, but how do i get the property name?

```
getMultiPicklistValues(fieldName) {
        var valuesArray = [];
        for(let i=0;i<this.assets.length;i++) {
            if(!valuesArray.includes(this.assets[i].get[fieldName])) {
                valuesArray.push(this.assets[i].get[fieldName]);
            }
        }
        var newArray = [];
        for(var i=0;i<valuesArray.length;i++) {
            newArray.push({'key':i+1,'value':valuesArray[i]});
        }

        //this.daysOptions = newArray;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try this[fieldName] = newArray?

Comment: `fieldName` will be "Days", but i want to set the value to `this.daysOptions`

Comment: Oh, so add a second parameter, e.g. "targetFieldName", and try this[targetFieldName] = newArray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that an instance of a JavaScript class is just a JavaScript object and you can assign to a property of a JavaScript object either using:

```
theObject.propertyName = X;
```

or

```
theObject["propertyName"] = X;
```

You should, therefore, be able to use something like:

```
this[targetProperty] = newArray;
```

to set the component's property named by the targetProperty variable.

Comment: Thank you very much!